# SSH into remote host using jump box

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, ssh-keys

I have a current setup for my servers like below:

```
My computer ---> Jump box -----> Target server in private network
```

I connect to the jump box from my computer using command

```
ssh -A jumpbox
```

and from jump box to target server using

```
ssh target server
```

Now I want to directly connect to the target from my computer, I have tried `ProxyCommand` and I don't want to do `netcat` to connect to the target server. Then I came across ProxyJump and tried the following config

```
Host <some name to target>
    Hostname <IP of Target>
    User <My user name>
    ForwardAgent yes
    Port 22
    ProxyJump <IP of Jumpbox>
```

I am getting public key denied error, Can someone tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: What is the exact error message you're getting?

Comment: public key permission denied

Comment: Use `ssh -v` to debug.

Comment: Have you tried `ssh -L` or is that too ghetto?

Comment: I have not but I want to follow the ProxyJump command only as it is helpful for my usecase, can you guide me how to fix it or what I am doing wrong there?

Comment: Try running `ssh -v` and see if you get some more informative error messages.  Copy the output and add it to your question so we can see what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will work:

`ssh target.server -J jumpbox.server`